# Looking to get average speed for each ID in terms list and within a date range in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, kibana, average

I'm looking in kibana to get the average speed each of four road ids within a specific date range. I have this aggregation code that doesn't bring up an errors, but it also Gateway Time-out every time I try. The two fields are there, but I can't seem to build the aggregation well enough to get my intended averages. Can someone see what I'm doing incorrectly? Here is my query:

```
GET herev322_*/_search
{
  "aggs": {
  "ns2ids":{
    "filter": {
      "bool":{
        "must":[
          {
          "terms":{
            "nS2ID": [
              "102-4893", 
              "102-4894",
              "102+10103",
              "102+10104"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
        "range":{
            "pBT":{
              "from": "2021-01-01T07:00:00",
              "to": "2021-02-01T19:00:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
    },
      "aggs":{
        "avg_speed":{
          "avg":{
            "field": "speed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Gateway Time-out generally happens when the request processing takes longer than expected. Try the same query using CLI instead of Kibana. Because Kibana timeouts fast.